# Style children of shadow dom ::part element

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a web component that renders the following in the shadow dom:

```
<custom-banner>
  #shadow-root
    <div part="headertext">
      I am the header text!
    </div>
    ...
</custom-banner>
```

To style the `headertext`, the following css works great:

```
custom-banner::part(headertext) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Now say I have something like this:

```
<custom-banner>
  #shadow-root
    <div part="headertext">
      I am the header text!
      <span>I am the subheader text!</span>
    </div>
    ...
</custom-banner>
```

Is there a way to target the *children* of a shadow part? That is, something like this (which doesn't seem to work):

```
custom-banner::part(headertext) span {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

I realize that this sort of thing might undercut the whole purpose of `::part`, but maybe not?

To be clear, the subheader span is *not* a slotted child in this example. It is always part of the component and it *is* in the shadow dom. The examples above are meant to be the rendered component, in browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Alas, you can **only style** the `::part` **Node itself**.

Not children, that would defeat the `::part` purpose,
might as well allow **all** shadowDOM styling from the **outside** then. (*can't be done*)

The [exportparts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts) attribute can pass `part` definitions to parent Nodes

As mentioned in the comment;
You can specify a `<span part="subheader">`,
**OR** you could use a CSS property, **scoped** to the **part**, see `--subheader: blue`

It all depends how much and which control you want to give to the user of your component.

good blogs:

- [Why is my shadowDOM inheriting styles](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/)
- `::parts` by Monica Dinculescu (Google): https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/

```html
<style>
  body {
    /* note how 'inheritable styles' do style shadowDOM */
    font: 28px Arial;
    color: green;
  }
  custom-banner::part(headertext) {
    /* style shadowDOM from global CSS */
    background: pink;
    --subheader: blue;
  }
</style>

<custom-banner></custom-banner>

<script>
  customElements.define("custom-banner", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = `<style> span {  color:var(--subheader)  } </style>` +
                     `<div part="headertext">I am the header text!` +
                        `<span>I am the subheader text!</span>` +
                     `</div>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps overlooked in this answer: it can be done by adding the part attribute to the subheader span: `<span part="subheader"></span>`